# How can I use a property from Class A in a method of class B in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have the following Code:

```js
class Process {

    constructor(){
        this.failedattempts = 0
    }
    
    generateNumber(){
        this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
        document.getElementById("randomdisplay").innerHTML = this.randomNumber
        //this.guessNumber(this.randomNumber)
    }
    
    getNumber(test){
        var temp
        for (var i=0; i < test.elements.length; i++){
            temp = test.elements[i]
            //alert("getnumberloop iteration number " + i)
            if(temp.name){
                this.submittedContent = temp.value
            }
        }

        //alert(this.submittedContent)
    }

    guessNumber(){
        //alert(randomInput)
        //alert("submittedContent in guessNumber() is " + this.submittedContent)
        //alert("randomNumber in guessNumber() is " + this.randomNumber)
        if(this.submittedContent == this.randomNumber){
            document.getElementById("victorymessage").innerHTML = "You won!"
            document.getElementById("victorymessage").style.color = "red"
        }else{
            this.failedattempts++
            alert("failedattempts in guessnumber() is " + this.failedattempts)
        }
    }
}

class chartData {
    constructor () {
        this.processClone = new Process
    }
    displayfailedattempts(){
        alert("entered displayfailedattempts")
        alert(this.processClone.failedattempts)
    }
}

var processInstance = new Process
var chartDataInstance =  new chartData
//document.getElementById("randomdisplay").innerHTML = processinstance.guessNumber();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>game with graphs!</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" href="gamestyle.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="processInstance.generateNumber()">
        <div id="div1">
            <p>input number between 0 and 19 here</p>
            <p>random number is</p>
            <p id="randomdisplay"></p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="place">
                <input type="button" value="senden" onclick='processInstance.getNumber(this.form)'/>
            </form>
            <input type = "button" value = "evaluate" onclick="processInstance.guessNumber()"></input>
            <p id="victorymessage">did you win?</p>
            <input type = "button" value = "showattempts" onclick="chartDataInstance.displayfailedattempts()">
        </div>
        <script src="gamejs.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

The purpose of this whole thing was/is to practice processing userinput on the webpage via javascript. I chose this approach because I wanted to practice mainly with javascript and not bother with php and a server.

Later on I want to display for example the number of failed attempts in graphs created with chart.js. Thats why I called the second class where the output happens "chartData". Since determining the number of failed attempts is inherently connected to evaluating the users "tip", I've put it into the guessNumber() method.

Now, the main issue is that when I use a property thats derived from "Process" class, then the "displayfailedattempts()" method always displays "0". It seems the property inside ChartData class , although derived from process Class, is not visible there. 
I've tried numerous different attempts where I created a property inside process Class derived from ChartData class, but this didn't result in any success.
I wonder what other options I have?

For the sake of practice I'm trying to keep up the current approach with two classes as long as possible. I also try to avoid coding outside the classes, because I want to try out how far I can go in connecting the classes between each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic OOP design.

I do not know if your design is correct, but specific in the way you went, The `processInstance` should be receive the reference of the instance that already exists, rather than create a new one.
You can pass it to her as a constructor parameter:

```js
class Process {

    constructor(){
        this.failedattempts = 0
    }
    
    generateNumber(){
        this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
        document.getElementById("randomdisplay").innerHTML = this.randomNumber
        //this.guessNumber(this.randomNumber)
    }
    
    getNumber(test){
        var temp
        for (var i=0; i < test.elements.length; i++){
            temp = test.elements[i]
            //alert("getnumberloop iteration number " + i)
            if(temp.name){
                this.submittedContent = temp.value
            }
        }

        //alert(this.submittedContent)
    }

    guessNumber(){
        //alert(randomInput)
        //alert("submittedContent in guessNumber() is " + this.submittedContent)
        //alert("randomNumber in guessNumber() is " + this.randomNumber)
        if(this.submittedContent == this.randomNumber){
            document.getElementById("victorymessage").innerHTML = "You won!"
            document.getElementById("victorymessage").style.color = "red"
        }else{
            this.failedattempts++
            alert("failedattempts in guessnumber() is " + this.failedattempts)
        }
    }
}

class chartData {
    constructor (prc) {
        this.processClone = prc
    }
    displayfailedattempts(){
        alert("entered displayfailedattempts")
        alert(this.processClone.failedattempts)
    }
}

var processInstance = new Process
var chartDataInstance =  new chartData(processInstance )
//document.getElementById("randomdisplay").innerHTML = processinstance.guessNumber();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>game with graphs!</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" href="gamestyle.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="processInstance.generateNumber()">
        <div id="div1">
            <p>input number between 0 and 19 here</p>
            <p>random number is</p>
            <p id="randomdisplay"></p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="place">
                <input type="button" value="senden" onclick='processInstance.getNumber(this.form)'/>
            </form>
            <input type = "button" value = "evaluate" onclick="processInstance.guessNumber()"></input>
            <p id="victorymessage">did you win?</p>
            <input type = "button" value = "showattempts" onclick="chartDataInstance.displayfailedattempts()">
        </div>
        <script src="gamejs.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extends` from class `Process` and call `super()` to run `constructor` of parent class

```
class chartData extends Process {
        constructor () {
            super();
            // this.processClone = new Process
        }
        displayfailedattempts(){
            alert("entered displayfailedattempts")
            alert(this.failedattempts)
        }
    }

    // var processInstance = new Process
    var chartDataInstance =  new chartData();
    chartDataInstance.displayfailedattempts();
```

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/ZxZJXR)

Comment: Interesting, I didnt know anything about this so far xD
Whats considered better style? Using the extends/super syntax, or going with the "constructur(ObjArg)" syntax?

Comment: This is the part  of OOP javascript by using `Class`. There are no best style, the good style **I think** is: the project run good and can scalable, easy to maintenance, easy to read.